# Best way to parse coordinates string in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, coordinates

I am wondering which would be the best way to parse coordinates that come together in the same `string` in C++.

Examples:

```
1,5
42.324234,-2.656264
```

The result should be two `double` variables...

Comment: How do you want to parse a non-integer into a `long`?

Comment: I think he meant doubles.

Comment: Yep, sorry... edited...

Comment: So, have you tried something? If so, what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the format of the string is always like `x,y`, then this should be enough.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

double x, y;
char sep;
string str = "42.324234,-2.656264";
istringstream iss(str);

iss >> x;
iss >> sep;
iss >> y;
```

Comment: Very nice and clear answer... Please, correct "istrinstream" --> "stringstream" so others can find it usefull too... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Extract each line using `while (std::getline(stream, line))` and then initialise a `std::istringstream` with `line`. Then you can extract from it like so:

```
double x, y;
if (line_stream >> x &&
    line_stream.get() == ',' &&
    line_stream >> y) {
  // Extracted successfully
}
```